# Long integer values in pandas dataframe change when sent to SQLite database using to_sql

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I am using pandas to organize and manipulate data I am getting from the twitter API. The 'id' key returns a very long integer (`int64`) that pandas has no problem handling (i.e. `481496718320496643`).

However, when I send to SQL:

`df.to_sql('Tweets', conn, flavor='sqlite', if_exists='append', index=False)`

I now have tweet id: `481496718320496640` or something close to that number.

I converted the tweet id to `str` but Pandas SQLite Driver / SQLite still messes with the number. The data type in the SQLite database is `[tweet_id] INTEGER`. What is going on and how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: This works fine in SQLite itself. This sounds as if the pandas SQLite driver treats this as a floating-point number.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? And with or without sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue -- I am using SQLite Manager (Firefox Plugin) as a SQLite client. For whatever reason, SQLite Manager displays the tweet IDs incorrectly even though they are properly stored (i.e. when I query, I get the desired values). Very strange I must say. I downloaded a different SQLite client to view the data and it displays properly.